# Why is $\bar x$ irreducible in $\mathbb R[x, y]/(x^3-y^5)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $R=\mathbb R[x, y]/(x^3-y^5)$. Why is $\bar x$ irreducible in $R$?

Here's my attempt. Suppose that $\bar x$ is reducible. Then $\bar x = \bar p \bar q$ for some nonunits $\bar p, \bar q$ in $R$. So in $\mathbb R[x, y]$, $pq = x - (x^3-y^5)r$ for some $r\in \mathbb R[x, y]$. I tried to find a contradiction here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$R$ is isomorphic to the subring of the polynomial ring $\Bbb R[t]$
with $\overline x$ corresponding to $t^5$ and $\overline y$ to $t^3$. This contains polynomials
of the form
$$a_0+a_3t^3+a_5t^5+a_6t^6+a_8t^8+a_9t^9+\cdots+a_nt^n.$$
The only nontrivial factors of $t^5$ in $\Bbb R[t]$ which also lie in $R$
are the associates of $t^3$, but $t^3$ isn't a factor of $t^5$ in $R$,
since $t^5/t^3\notin R$.

Comment: I tried to show that the kernel of the homomorphism $\varphi: \mathbb R[x, y]\to \mathbb R[t]$ assigning $t^5$ to $x$ and $t^3$ to $y$ is $(x^3-y^5)$. I proved one inclusion, but how do I prove that $Ker(\varphi)\subseteq(x^3-y^5)$?

Comment: We can write $f(x, y) = f_0(y) + f_1(y) x + f_2(y) x^2 + g$ for some $g \in (x^3 - y^5)$. If $f(t^5, t^3) \equiv 0$, we have $f_0(t^3) + f_1(t^3) t^5 + f_2(t^3) t^{10} \equiv 0$. The degrees of the monomials in each of these three summands are distinct mod 3. Taking $t \to \infty$ and considering leading terms forces each summand to be identically zero. Taking cube roots (which is invertible over $\mathbb{R}$) gives $f_0(y) = f_1(y) = f_2(y) = 0$, so $f \in (x^3 - y^5)$ after all.

Comment: @Jswanson I don't understand why $f(x, y)$ can always be written in that form. Isn't it impossible to write $x^3$ like that?

Comment: @zxcv Long division with respect to $x$. For $x^3$ we have $x^3=y^5+(x^3-y^5)$.

Comment: Now I get it. Thanks everyone!